# How do I link my pages in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created 4 different pages in wordpress , my own theme , and have tried different php codes. I have heard `<?php get_permalink(); ?>` is suppose to work but do not understand how to use it and I do not want to download any files and start again. PLEASE HELP

Comment: Yes, `get_permalink( $post_id )` will work inside Wordpress. You have to be more specific in describing your problem. If you don't understand how to use a PHP function then you need to go and read some tutorials.

Comment: I kinda realized that but I have watch many videos and more but all they are doing is creating links within the WP page and not through PHP ,even when I look up how to do it in PHP thats why I am asking on this

Answer (score 0):

`<?php get_permalink(); ?>` works when it's inside the loop to link back to posts, etc.

If you want to link to another page, I would use:

```
<?php echo home_url(); ?>/page-name
```

So to link to other pages, this can work:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/page-name">Page Name</a>
```

Comment: would I put the gallery.php for example within the brackets ??

Comment: @htmljoecss yes... so for example: <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/gallery.php">Gallery</a>

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I think you're just talking html here. The `<?php get_permalink(); ?>`  and, indeed all TheCenteno's addtional solutions, only work if you've created the page through WordPress (that is, logged in and clicked the 'Add New Page' menu item. If you just hand coded these pages (which is what is sounds like) you've just got to use standard html link syntax

```
<a href='gallery.php'>view gallery</a>
```

Just make sure you're pages (gallery.php for example) are in the correct directory or use an absolute url:

```
 <a href='http://www.mywebsite.com/gallery.php'>view gallery</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way with out loop is

`$link = get_permalink($page_id);`

where

`$page_id` is the id of your desired page. And then

`<a href="<?php echo $link?>"></a>`